# How to test the grid API is available for ag-grid in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, ag-grid

I an trying to write the unit test using jasmine for ag-grid.

1. HTMl

   ```
    <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    rowSelection='single'
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    >
    </ag-grid-angular>
   ```
2. .ts

   ```
    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
    import { DataGrid } from 'src/app/shared/models/datagrid.model';
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-simple-view',
    templateUrl: './simple-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./simple-view.component.scss']
    })
    export class SimpleViewComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('data') data: any | undefined;

    columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'Geography', sortable: true },
    { field: 'Category', sortable: true },
    { field: 'DataType', sortable: true }
   ];

   rowData: DataGrid[] | undefined;

   public gridApi: any;

   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rowData = this.data;
   }

   onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;

   }
   }
   ```
3. spec.ts

   ```
    it('grid API is available after `detectChanges`', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.gridOptions.api).toBeTruthy();
    });
   ```

this test method is failing with the below error

SimpleViewComponent > grid API is available after `detectChanges`
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
at 
at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/src/app/features/overview/components/simple-view/simple-view.component.spec.ts:45:31)
at Generator.next ()
at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)

Comment: Do you have the `AgGrid` modules in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`?

Comment: Yes I have imported that

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of situations (Not knowing when AGGrid will resolve what it will resolve), I like to use a `waitUntil` utility function.

```
// Put this in a utils section of the project with the name of waitUntil.ts
// This function will keep retrying and wait until the function is truthy
// before proceeding

import { interval } from 'rxjs';
.....
export const waitUntil = async (untilTruthy: Function): Promise<boolean> => {
  while (!untilTruthy()) {
    await interval(25).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```

```
// Use waitUntil with async await

it('grid API is available after `detectChanges`', async () => {
   fixture.detectChanges();
   // wait until gridOptions.api is truthy
   await waitUntil(() => !!component.gridOptions.api);
   expect(component.gridOptions.api).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

I remember when I was using `AgGrid` with Angular unit tests, I had to use `waitUntil` a lot. If that test times out (the await does not resolve), then I am thinking there is something wrong with the setup of the test.